# Firebase cloud mesaging - vibration and led notification lights not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using firebase cloud messaging to send push notifications on my android app. 
Below is the object I am using:

```
 android: {
    priority: 'HIGH',
    notification: {
      sound: 'default',
      notification_priority: 'PRIORITY_MAX',
      default_vibrate_timings: true,
      default_light_settings: true,
    },
  },
```

However, the phone does not vibrate or show led notifications. I have also added the vibration permission to the manifest file.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this @hitzy ? even i have same issue, in some devices allow notification and allow sound is turned off by default. I need to got to notifications settings and enable it manually.